# How to get sum of time field in SQL server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am facing a problem in finding the sum of values stored in a column,

I have a table like this:

```
gs_cycle_no    | from_time   | to_time  | total_hours(varchar) ...
GSC-334/2012   | 13:00       | 7:00     |  42:00
GSC-334/2012   | 8:30        | 3:45     |  6:00
.
.
.
```

What i need to find is the `Sum(total_hours)` group by `gs_cycle_no`.
But the `Sum` method will not work on the varchar column and also i cant convert it to decimal due to its format,

How can i find the `sum` of `total_hours` column, based on `gs_cycle_no`?

Comment: what does the value `42:00` represent? 42 hours and 0 minutes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you have no minutes and only hours, then you can do something like:

```
select
    cast(sum(cast(replace(total_hours, ':', '') as int) / 100) as nvarchar(max)) + ':00'
from Table1
group by gs_cycle_no
```

if you don't, try this:

```
with cte as
(
    select
        gs_cycle_no,
        sum(cast(left(total_hours, len(total_hours) - 3) as int)) as h,
        sum(cast(right(total_hours, 2) as int)) as m
    from Table1
    group by gs_cycle_no
)
select
    gs_cycle_no,
    cast(h + m / 60 as nvarchar(max)) + ':' +
    right('00' + cast(m % 60 as nvarchar(max)), 2)
from cte
```

[**sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/998d9/5)

Comment: first one work only for whole hours as written, missed group by in second, thanks for that

Comment: @OzrenTkalcecKrznaric how did you test that? :)

Comment: Now it's fine... +1; btw I would remove first solution, it's misleading

Comment: @OzrenTkalcecKrznaric it was fine right from the start, just missed group by clause when tested

Comment: @DadapeerPvg almost? :)

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
;with times as (
    select gs_cycle_no = 'GSC-334/2012', total_hours = '8:35'
    union all SELECT gs_cycle_no = 'GSC-334/2012', '5:00'
    union all SELECT gs_cycle_no = 'GSC-334/2012', '16:50'
    union all SELECT gs_cycle_no = 'GSC-334/2012', '42:00'
    union all SELECT gs_cycle_no = 'GSC-335/2012', '0:00'
    union all SELECT gs_cycle_no = 'GSC-335/2012', '175:52'
    union all SELECT gs_cycle_no = 'GSC-335/2012', '12:25')
SELECT
    gs_cycle_no,
    hrs = sum(mins) / 60 + sum(hrs),
    mins = sum(mins) % 60
FROM 
    TIMES
    cross apply(
        select c = charindex(':', total_hours)
    ) idx
    cross apply(
        select
            hrs = cast(substring(total_hours, 1, c - 1) as int),
            mins = cast(substring(total_hours, c + 1, len(total_hours)) as int)
    ) ext
group by gs_cycle_no
order by gs_cycle_no
```

Answer (score 0):

This query finds sum in minutes:

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f52a8/13)

```
select gs_cycle_no,

  SUM(
  CAST(
  ISNULL(
  substring(total_hours,1,CHARINDEX(':',total_hours)-1)
  ,'0') as INT) * 60
   +
   CAST(
   ISNULL(
   substring(total_hours,CHARINDEX(':',total_hours)+1,100)
   ,'0') as INT) 
   ) 
   from t
group by   gs_cycle_no
```

Comment: Resultset outputs minutes, instead of hours

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution where I break varchar into two small pieces, hours and minutes, and then make minutes from them, and at last, SUM them:

```
SELECT 
    gs_cycle_no, 
    CAST(SUM(
        SUBSTRING(total_hours,0 ,CHARINDEX(':', total_hours)) * 60 +
        SUBSTRING(total_hours, CHARINDEX(':', total_hours) + 1, LEN(total_hours)))  / 60 AS VARCHAR) + ':' + 
    CAST(SUM(
        SUBSTRING(total_hours,0 ,CHARINDEX(':', total_hours)) * 60 +
        SUBSTRING(total_hours, CHARINDEX(':', total_hours) + 1, LEN(total_hours))) % 60 AS VARCHAR)
FROM Table1
GROUP BY gs_cycle_no
```